# Hibernate annotation one to one uni-directional

Tags: hibernate, annotations

Why I am I getting following number(4) of sql statements in my one to one hibernate mapping example(Uni-directional), I get only 2 insert statements for same examples in simple hbm configuration.

For annotation sql statements are as follows:

Hibernate: select persondeta_.id, persondeta_.fatherName as fatherName1_, persondeta_.motherName as motherName1_ from PersonDetail persondeta_ where persondeta_.id=?

Hibernate: insert into Person (email, firstName, lastName, personDetail_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into PersonDetail (fatherName, motherName, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: update Person set email=?, firstName=?, lastName=?, personDetail_id=? where id=?

For hbm sql statements are as follows

Hibernate: insert into Person (email, firstName, lastName, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into PersonDetail (fatherName, motherName, id) values (?, ?, ?)

My hbm configuration as follows

```
<class name="com.patel.model.Person">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="firstName" />
    <property name="lastName" />
    <property name="email" />
    <one-to-one name="personDetail" class="com.patel.model.Persondetail" />
</class>
<class name="com.patel.model.PersonDetail">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="fatherName" />
    <property name="motherName" />
</class>
```

My Annotations class are as follows :

package com.patel.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity

public class Person {

```
@Id
private int id;
@Column
private String firstName;
@Column
private String lastName;
@Column
private String email;

@OneToOne
private PersonDetail personDetail;

public Person() {
    super();
}

public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName="
            + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
}

public PersonDetail getPersonDetail() {
    return personDetail;
}

public void setPersonDetail(PersonDetail personDetail) {
    this.personDetail = personDetail;
}
```

}

package com.patel.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity

public class PersonDetail {

```
@Id
private int id;
@Column
private String fatherName;
@Column
private String motherName;

public PersonDetail() {
    super();
}

public PersonDetail(int id, String fatherName, String motherName) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.fatherName = fatherName;
    this.motherName = motherName;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFatherName() {
    return fatherName;
}

public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {
    this.fatherName = fatherName;
}

public String getMotherName() {
    return motherName;
}

public void setMotherName(String motherName) {
    this.motherName = motherName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PersonDetail [id=" + id + ", fatherName=" + fatherName
            + ", motherName=" + motherName + "]";
}
```

}

Here is the code that causes the query

package com.patel.client;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.TransactionException;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

import com.patel.model.Person;

import com.patel.model.PersonDetail;

public class JpaClient {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Person p = new Person(1, "Bhupati", "Patel", "xyz@xyz.com");
        PersonDetail pd = new PersonDetail(1, "Bhupatis's Father", "Bhupati's Mother");
        p.setPersonDetail(pd);

        session.save(p);
        session.save(pd);
        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("Inserted");

    } catch (TransactionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();
    }

}
```

}

In hbm file's client code :

SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

remaining are same

Using which annotation configuration I will get two insert statements as hbm configuration ?

Comment: Where is the code that causes these queries to be executed?

Comment: I have added it just now.

Comment: Try adding `optional=false` to your OneToOne annotation.

Comment: After adding it its gives following error(I am pasting part of it) Hibernate: select persondeta_.id, persondeta_.fatherName as fatherName1_, persondeta_.motherName as motherName1_ from PersonDetail persondeta_ where persondeta_.id=?
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.patel.model.Person.personDetail

Comment: The PersonDetail must be saved first, since the Person references it.

Comment: Hmm, got the mistake. Its working now, it gives output like Hibernate: insert into PersonDetail (fatherName, motherName, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Person (email, firstName, lastName, personDetail_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) . However, in my previous hbm configuration it was giving like Hibernate: insert into PersonDetail (fatherName, motherName, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Person (email, firstName, lastName, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) . Here t no reference column in Person table. Is there a way to achieve same thing in annotation ?

Comment: Then your previous hbm config was buggy: the association between Person and PersonDetails wasn't stored anywhere.

Comment: Hmm, make sense. I will go deeper in to hbm and annotations. Thanks.